# How to create ng-pattern not allowing uppercase

Tags: regex, angularjs

How to create ng-pattern in angular not allowing input in uppercase?Thanks in advance. Like this pattern. ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your example to `ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/"`. This regex will fail if it finds any upper case letters. You just needed to remove the `A-Z` from your example so the regular expression knows not to allow them.

Comment: Thank you @j_buckly but how can i use this pattern not also allow to input a number? I mean Uppercase and numbers are not allowing to input in a text field.

Comment: To disallow numbers as well you just remove the `0-9` from the expression. So you'd have `ng-pattern="/^[a-z]*$/"` which allows any amount (the * means 0 or more times) of lowercase letters. Check out an introduction to regular expressions if you want to learn how they work, it's pretty interesting what you can do with them. Here's a decent intro to [regex](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html)

Comment: Thanks you again for helping me and giving me an idea. Well appreciated.=) @j_buckly

Comment: How to allow special characters too?